# treemacs cannot open function in another window

Tags: treemacs

I'm getting `file-name-extension: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil` when opening a function in Treemacs.

If I open the variable defined in that function, then it works fine. The line of the variable gets opened in the window but when I do the same for the function, it errors out:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  file-name-nondirectory(nil)
  file-name-extension(nil)
  treemacs--visit-or-expand/collapse-tag-node(#<marker (moves after insertion) at 636 in  *Treemacs-Scoped-Buffer-No Tab*> nil nil)
  treemacs-visit-node-no-split(nil)
  funcall-interactively(treemacs-visit-node-no-split nil)
  call-interactively(treemacs-visit-node-no-split)
  treemacs-rightclick-menu((mouse-3 (#<window 161 on  *Treemacs-Scoped-Buffer-No Tab*> 647 (228 . 665) 48575959 nil 647 (26 . 30) nil (6 . 5) (8 . 17))))
  funcall-interactively(treemacs-rightclick-menu (mouse-3 (#<window 161 on  *Treemacs-Scoped-Buffer-No Tab*> 647 (228 . 665) 48575959 nil 647 (26 . 30) nil (6 . 5) (8 . 17))))
  call-interactively(treemacs-rightclick-menu nil nil)
  command-execute(treemacs-rightclick-menu)
```

Does anyone know what I can do I fix this problem?

Furthermore, when I click "enter" on the function instead of using the mouse, treemacs duplicates the contents of the file. By this I mean, if the function looked like this:

```
    | --f
        |-- var1
        |-- var2
```

After pressing enter, treemacs looks like this:

```
    | --f
        |-- var1
        |-- var2
        |-- var1
        |-- var2
```

If I press enter again, it'll add `var1`, `var2` for the third time and so on.

It very strange. How do I fix this?

Here is the debugger when I press `o-o` on a function or class in Treemacs:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  file-name-nondirectory(nil)
  file-name-extension(nil)
  treemacs--visit-or-expand/collapse-tag-node(#<marker (moves after insertion) at 469 in  *Treemacs-Scoped-Buffer-No Tab*> nil nil)
  treemacs-visit-node-no-split(nil)
  funcall-interactively(treemacs-visit-node-no-split nil)
  call-interactively(treemacs-visit-node-no-split nil nil)
  command-execute(treemacs-visit-node-no-split)
```